# Django cache and page part that depends on login

Tags: django

Suppose I have some page at example.com/page
If a user is not logged in, then I show Log in button. If the user is logged in, then I show menu.

The problem is that it doesn't work with cache.
If I render page and save it in cache, then it is always with login button.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are caching the entire view or template. So instead of that, you should cache only the relevant fragment of code, in the template:

```
{% load cache %}

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
   {% cache 500 sidebar menu%}
      .. menu for logged in user ..
   {% endcache %}
{% else %}
   ... the login button goes here...
{% endif %}
```

see more details in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching):